# How to read a text data into pandas dataframe which is partially in key value format

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

File content of file `test`:

```
costCenter: LL63238012
mail: shiva.gowni@LLp.com
LLpResponsible: cn=LLf58420,ou=Personal,ou=People,ou=LLDI,o=LLP
LLpHomeDirectory: nisMapName=auto.home,ou=RDC_AMEC_LL-CDC01,ou=Locations,ou=LLDI,o=LLP#0#Quality=economy,NisMap=llc1002:/proj/llc1002_ziz1/q,Quota=10621
LLpHomeDirectory: nisMapName=auto.home,ou=RDC_AMEC_LL-CDC01,ou=Locations,ou=LLDI,o=LLP#0#Quality=scratKG,NisMap=llc1002:/proj/llc1002_ziz1_scratKG/q,Quota=12000,Id=scratKG
fullName: Tulip project ziz1

costCenter: MX61FRK604
mail: ali.pina@LLp.com
LLpResponsible: cn=LLa11826,ou=Personal,ou=People,ou=LLDI,o=LLP
LLpHomeDirectory: nisMapName=auto.home,ou=SAT_AMEC_MX-GDL01,ou=Locations,ou=LLDI,o=LLP#0#Quality=reference,NisMap=llc0156:/proj/llc0156_zmx28home_3/q,Quota=100,Id=3
LLpHomeDirectory: nisMapName=auto.home,ou=SAT_AMEC_MX-GDL01,ou=Locations,ou=LLDI,o=LLP#0#Quality=reference,NisMap=llc0156:/proj/llc0156_zmx28home/q,Quota=300
LLpHomeDirectory: nisMapName=auto.home,ou=SAT_AMEC_MX-GDL01,ou=Locations,ou=LLDI,o=LLP#0#Quality=reference,NisMap=llc0156:/proj/llc0156_zmx28home_2/q,Quota=100,Id=2
fullName: xFSL to LLDI migration



costCenter: RU61FPD561
mail: udi.landen@LLp.com
LLpResponsible: cn=LLa09278,ou=Personal,ou=People,ou=LLDI,o=LLP
LLpHomeDirectory: nisMapName=auto.home,ou=RDC_AMEC_LL-CDC01,ou=Locations,ou=LLDI,o=LLP#0#Quota=1,Quality=EconomyHP,NisMap=llc2002:/proj/llc2002_zru12/q
LLpHomeDirectory: nisMapName=auto.home,ou=RDC_AMEC_LL-CDC01,ou=Locations,ou=LLDI,o=LLP#0#Quota=2800,Quality=EconomyHP,NisMap=llc1002:/proj/llc1002_zru12_analog/q,Id=analog
LLpHomeDirectory: nisMapName=auto.home,ou=RDC_AMEC_LL-CDC01,ou=Locations,ou=LLDI,o=LLP#0#Quota=1100,Quality=EconomyHP,NisMap=llc1002:/proj/llc1002_zru12_home/q,Id=home
LLpHomeDirectory: nisMapName=auto.home,ou=RDC_AMEC_LL-CDC01,ou=Locations,ou=LLDI,o=LLP#0#Quality=EconomyHP,NisMap=llc1002:/proj/llc1002_zru12_libddk/q,Quota=2162,Id=libddk
LLpHomeDirectory: nisMapName=auto.home,ou=RDC_AMEC_LL-CDC01,ou=Locations,ou=LLDI,o=LLP#0#Quality=EconomyHP,NisMap=llc1002:/proj/llc1002_zru12_proj/q,Quota=1102,Id=proj
fullName: zru12

costCenter: KG63010285
mail: adam.smith@LLp.com
LLpHomeDirectory: nisMapName=auto.home,ou=RDC_EMEA_NL-CDC01,ou=Locations,ou=LLDI,o=LLP#0#Quality=BLLinessCriticalHP,Quota=60,NisMap=llc4008:/proj/llc4008_zuriKG/q
fullName: Container to store ZuriKG vault



costCenter: KG63010285
mail: adam.smith@LLp.com
LLpHomeDirectory: nisMapName=auto.home,ou=RDC_EMEA_NL-CDC01,ou=Locations,ou=LLDI,o=LLP#0#Quality=EconomyHP,Quota=1,NisMap=llc3008:/proj/llc3008_zuriKG_rme/q
LLpHomeDirectory: nisMapName=auto.home,ou=SAT_EMEA_NL-RME01,ou=Locations,ou=LLDI,o=LLP#0#Quality=EconomyHP,Quota=30,NisMap=llc4014:/proj/llc4014_zuriKG_rme/q
LLpHomeDirectory: nisMapName=auto.home,ou=SAT_EMEA_NL-RME01,ou=Locations,ou=LLDI,o=LLP#0#Quality=ScratKGHP,Quota=400,NisMap=llc4014:/proj/llc4014_zuriKG_rme_scratKG/q,Id=scratKG
fullName: Project to restore  project data on the RME work on HP-UX
```

**Code which i am using:**

```
def generate(data):
    for record in data.split("\n\n"):              # Split records based on two newlines (unix)
        result = {}
        for line in record.split("\n"):            # Split properties based on single newlines (unix)
            if line:                               # Skip empty lines happening for extra or trailing newlines
                key, *value = line.split(": ")     # Tolerant to lines with more than a single ´: ´ (*values)
                value = ": ".join(value)           # Recover original value if more than a single (`: `)
                if key in result:
                    result[key] += ";" + value
                else:
                    result[key] = value
        if result:                                 # Don't yield empty results
            yield result


frame = pd.DataFrame(generate("test"))
print(frame)

#frame["responsible"] = frame["LLpResponsible"].str.extract("cn=([\w]*)")
frame["location"] = frame["LLpHomeDirectory"].str.extract("ou=([\w_\-]*)")
frame["directory"] = frame["LLpHomeDirectory"].str.findall("NisMap=\w+:([\w_\-/]*)")

df1 = frame[['costCenter',  'mail', 'responsible', 'location', 'directory']]
#df2 = df.explode("directory")[["costCenter", "responsible", "directory", "mail", "location"]]
print(df1)
```

**Error:**

When i am running this, i am getting below ....

```
 $ python ldapDataParse1
  test
0
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/core/indexes/base.py", line 2898, in get_loc
    return self._engine.get_loc(casted_key)
  File "pandas/_libs/index.pyx", line 70, in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc
  File "pandas/_libs/index.pyx", line 101, in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc
  File "pandas/_libs/hashtable_class_helper.pxi", line 1675, in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item
  File "pandas/_libs/hashtable_class_helper.pxi", line 1683, in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item
KeyError: 'LLpHomeDirectory'

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "ldapDataParse1", line 30, in <module>
    frame["location"] = frame["LLpHomeDirectory"].str.extract("ou=([\w_\-]*)")
  File "/home/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/core/frame.py", line 2906, in __getitem__
    indexer = self.columns.get_loc(key)
  File "/home/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/core/indexes/base.py", line 2900, in get_loc
    raise KeyError(key) from err
KeyError: 'LLpHomeDirectory'
```

Comment: Please check your question again. It is really confusing, no idea what your question actually is.

Comment: @Rabinzel, i have updated the Post , I am looking forward to read the file directly which has the same data as provided  in the sample.

Comment: you say that the `generate` function isn't working. what do you mean? there's a million ways a block of code will be broken, but only one way that it can be correct.

Comment: @PaulH, May be simply i need to say how to read this type of data into the Pandas data frame may be .. let me make it simpler, the problem i am having is that using the data into like `data = """  raw data """ ` its working with the function but when directly providing file it does not.

Comment: but the question you linked to achieves that. what error are you getting? what is happening and how is it different than what you expect to happen?

Comment: I was just thinking exactly the same. in the accepted answer are two versions and the initial version is exactly doing what you are asking in this new question.

Comment: Looks like i'm miserably failed to explain, let me try to explain better in the post.

Comment: just to be clear. the data and code you posted in this question here is taking a big string as input and converts it to a dataframe. That is working right? Why do we need it then (you can remove that from the question)? Show us the data of the `.txt` file you want to read, together with the code you use to run it. AND (important!) we need the exact error you get.

Comment: @Rabinzel, yes that's working.. i updated the Post, thanks for all your suggestions .

Comment: ok. why do you use the generate function of version 2 of the answer in the other question? You need to use the function provided in the initial version.

Comment: Because initial version did not worked as the second version takes care of extra newlines as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to copy paste those two functions together, the original autor even gave you the comments what the code does.
You need the context manager (with open(...)...) to open the file and then after `for record in handler.read().split("\n\n")` you just use the 2nd version of the answer to take care of extra newlines.

```
def generate(file):
    with open(file) as handler:
        for record in handler.read().split("\n\n"):
            result = {}
            for line in record.split("\n"):
                if line:
                    key, *value = line.split(": ")
                    value = ": ".join(value)
                    if key in result:
                        result[key] += ";" + value
                    else:
                        result[key] = value
            if result:
                yield result
```

```
frame = pd.DataFrame(generate("test.txt"))

frame["responsible"] = frame["LLpResponsible"].str.extract("cn=([\w]*)")
frame["location"] = frame["LLpHomeDirectory"].str.extract("ou=([\w_\-]*)")
frame["directory"] = frame["LLpHomeDirectory"].str.findall("NisMap=\w+:([\w_\-/]*)")
print(frame[["costCenter", "responsible", "directory"]])
```

Output:

```
   costCenter responsible                                          directory
0  MX61FRK604    LLa11826  [/proj/llc0156_zmx28home_3/q, /proj/llc0156_zm...
1  RU61FPD561    LLa09278  [/proj/llc2002_zru12/q, /proj/llc1002_zru12_an...
2  KG63010285         NaN                           [/proj/llc4008_zuriKG/q]
3  KG63010285         NaN  [/proj/llc3008_zuriKG_rme/q, /proj/llc4014_zur...
```